# Получение времени из строки

Tags: java

Возможно ли реализовать такую штуку: есть строка. В ней может быть написано `1year`/`1month`/`1week`/`1day`/`1hour`/`1minute`/`1second` или несколько вместе. Например: `1week5day`. И мы должны получить время в миллисекундах, которое занимает данный промежуток времени. Если возможно, то подтолкните, а то я сам не догоняю.

Comment: Возможно. Сделать обработку строки, вытаскивая значения и вид (значение = количество, вид = единица изменения, например, год). После останется сопоставить вид к количеству миллисекунд, умножить на количество и суммировать всё это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сложную задачу нужно делить по частям:

1. Парсинг текста. Для получения количества и единицы измерения времени (`year`, `month`, ...). Мне кажется, в вашем случае, самое удобное это через регулярные выражения.
2. Сопоставление единицы измерения времени к количеству миллисекунд
3. Суммирование миллисекунд

Покажу примеры шагов, но с **неполной** реализацией

1. Тут в регулярном выражении я указываю, что ожидается число и единица измерения (остальные сами добавите, разделяя их вертикальной чертой)

   ```
   String text = "1week5day10hour";

   Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)(week|day|hour)").matcher(text);
   while (m.find()) {
       int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
       String kind = m.group(2);
       System.out.println(number + " " + kind);
   }
   ```

   Результатом будет:

   ```
   1 week
   5 day
   10 hour
   ```
2. Можно это сделать через `if`/`switch`, но я сделаю через словарь. Кст, в этом случае удобно сделать регулярное выражение от ключей словаря, чтобы не повторяться в словаре и в шаблоне регулярки.

   ```
   Map<String, Long> kindByMs = new HashMap<String, Long>() {{
       put("week", 604800000L);
       put("day", 86400000L);
       put("hour", 3600000L);
   }};

   Matcher m = <регулярка>
   while (m.find()) {
       int number = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
       String kind = m.group(2);
       long ms = kindByMs.get(kind);
       System.out.println(kind + " = " + ms + " ms");
   }
   ```

   Результат:

   ```
   week = 604800000 ms
   day = 86400000 ms
   hour = 3600000 ms
   ```
3. Для сложения используйте переменную с типом `long`, но, возможно, лучше через большие числа, т.е. через [BigInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html)

Comment: Благодарю. Overfow не дает отметить 2 решения...

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn, пожалуйста :)

Comment: я пытаюсь че-то сделать с этим, но меня ругает за Pattern.  The method Pattern(String) is undefined for the type String.

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn, добавьте импорты к этим классам `import java.util.regex.Matcher;` `import java.util.regex.Pattern;`

Comment: Ага, спасибо. Просто eclipse не очень хотел показывать импорт. Хотя Matcher нормально импортировал.

Answer (score 1):

Можно еще при помощи сканера, стримов и таймюнитов (последнее для упрощения конвертации):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner("1hour10minute");
    System.out.println(
            scanner
            .findAll("(\\d+)(second|minute|hour|day|week|month|year)")
            .map(matchResult ->
                Long
                        .valueOf(TimeUnit.valueOf((matchResult.group(2) + "s")
                                .toUpperCase())
                                .toMillis(Integer.valueOf(matchResult.group(1))))
            ).reduce((aLong, aLong2) -> aLong + aLong2).orElse(0L)
    );
}
```

Что тут происходит?

- `findAll` разбивает строку на токены "число-период" и приводит всё это к стриму.
- `map` приводит каждый элемент стрима к миллисекундам. Для этого он использует стандартную сущность `TimeUnit`. Т.к. таймюниты из задачи отличаются от нужного представления только единственным числом, мы просто добавляем `s` в конец.
- `reduce` схлопывает наш стрим в число через сложение отдельных элементов.

Comment: ругается на `findAll`

Comment: Каким образом ругается? Какая входная строка?

Comment: @ZiEnTenIn `findAll` появляется с джавы версии 9. П.С. - если ответ не подходит Вы можете снять галочку "правильный ответ" и отметить другой ответ.

Comment: @Alexye R. The method findAll(String) is undefined for the type String. Как я понимаю - ругается на тип String;